# Django QuestionForm in forms.py not Creating Instance in questions.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a QuestionForm in forms.py meant to create instances of a Question model to appear in questions.html. However, when I submit the form, I am redirected back to ask_question.html without any new instance being created.

## Debugging Steps:

### 1. Admin Panel Creation

I am able to create an instance of the Question model through the Django admin panel, which is currently the only instance displaying.

### 2. Frontend Submission

I have tried creating an instance of the Question model using the front end, and no error message appears. However, no instance of the Question model appears in the questions.html template.

### 3. I inspected `QuestionForm` in `forms.py`

it appears to be working as intended.

```py
    class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, help_text='Enter a subject line for your question.')
        body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=10000, required=True, help_text='Enter the main body of your question.')
        teacher_standard = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            required=False,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices=[(1, 'High Expectations'), (2, 'Promoting Progress'), (3, 'Subject Knowledge'), (4, 'Planning'), (5, 'Differentiation'), (6, 'Assessment'), (7, 'Behaviour Management'), (8, 'Professionalism')],
            help_text='Select the standard(s) for which you are asking the question.'
        )
        class Meta:
            model = Question  
            fields = ['subject', 'body', 'teacher_standard']
```

### 4. inspecting the `Question` model in `models.py`

it appears to be working as intended.

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question_posts")
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='questionpost_upvote', blank=True)
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='questionpost_downvote', blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField
    standards = models.ManyToManyField(TeachingStandardTag, related_name='questions', blank=True)
    answercount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def number_of_upvotes(self):
        return self.upvotes.count()
```

### 5. inspecting the `ask_question.html` template

it appears to be working as intended.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Ask a Question</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject line">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Question:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="body" name="body" rows="5" placeholder="Enter the main body of your question"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="teacher_standard">Teacher Standard:</label>
            {% for value, text in form.teacher_standard.field.choices %}
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="teacher_standard" id="teacher_standard_{{value}}" value="{{value}}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="teacher_standard_{{value}}">
                    {{text}}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

### 6. creating two different form validations in `views.py`

that would traceback the issue. However neither appears to change anything, no instance of the question appears in `questions.html` upon submission of the form.

```py
class QuestionCreate(generic.CreateView): # this class will create a question
    model = Question
    template_name = "ask_question.html" # template for the create question pageddd
    fields = ["title", "slug", "author"]

    def ask_question(request): # this function will ask a question
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                question = form.save(commit=False)
                question.author = request.user  # assuming you have user authentication
                question.save()
                return redirect('questions')  # or wherever you want to redirect after successful submission
            else:
                print(form.errors)  # Helps debug what's wrong with the form
        else:
            form = QuestionForm()
        return render(request, 'ask_question.html', {'form': form})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed. It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.instance.author = self.request.user  # Assign the author to the user submitting the form
        return super().form_valid(form)

[...]

    def question(self, request, *args, **kwargs): #renamed from post to postquestion
        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Handle the form submission and create a new Question instance
            new_question = Question.objects.create(
                title=form.cleaned_data['subject'],
                content=form.cleaned_data['body'],
                author=request.user,
                slug=form.cleaned_data['subject'],
                status=1
            )
            new_question.save()
        return render(request, 'ask_question.html', {'form': form})
```

### 7. simplify the `QuestionCreate` class in `views.py`

however it does not appear to change anything, no instance of the question appears to be created upon submission of the form.

```py
class QuestionCreate(generic.CreateView): # this class will create a question
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm  # Use the custom form class
    template_name = "ask_question.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        # Generate a slug from the subject or use any other field as necessary
        form.instance.slug = form.cleaned_data['subject'].replace(' ', '-').lower()
        return super(QuestionCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Redirect to the 'questions' page after form submission
        return reverse_lazy('questions')
```

8. simplifying the `ask_question.html` class in views.py with {{ form.as_p }}

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Ask a Question</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }} <!-- This will render all the fields using the form instance -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Which leads to a new error message upon form submission:

```
IntegrityError at /ask_question/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blog_question_title_key"
DETAIL:  Key (title)=() already exists.
```

### 9. checked the Javascript console

no error messages.

### 10. updated the `QuestionForm` class in `forms.py` to include the `title`.

This fixes the error message in step 8 but does not create an apparent instance.

```py
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, help_text='Enter a subject line for your question.')
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=10000, required=True, help_text='Enter the main body of your question.')
    teacher_standard = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=[(1, 'High Expectations'), (2, 'Promoting Progress'), (3, 'Subject Knowledge'), (4, 'Planning'), (5, 'Differentiation'), (6, 'Assessment'), (7, 'Behaviour Management'), (8, 'Professionalism')],
        help_text='Select the standard(s) for which you are asking the question.'
    )

    class Meta:
        """
        the Meta class is used to specify the model to which the form is associated and the fields from the model you want the form to include.
        """
        model = Question  # Specifies the model in models.py associated with this form
        fields = ['title', 'subject', 'body', 'teacher_standard']  # The fields from the model you want the form to include
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have posted the steps to solving the issue.

I soon realised upon inspection that between step 6 or 7 I was able to store questions on the backend.

## debugging steps continued

### 11. Django Admin review

I have double checked Django Admin to see if any of my test forms have been created in the back end. They have! However, they are not appearing in the front end. I want them to appear in `questions.html`.

```
    test3 (does not appear in questions.html)   subject3    Draft   Dec. 22, 2023, 12:21 p.m.
    testpost1   testpost1   Published   Dec. 18, 2023, 6:57 p.m.
```

### 12.  inspect details to spot draft/published status

Upon inspection I can see that test3 is a Draft, which might explain why it isn't uploading. When I change the status to Published, it does appear in `questions.html`. So it appears that the issue now is that the form is not submitting as Published, but as Draft.

### 13. adjust the `form_valid` method in `views.py`

I am trying to ensure that the status field of the Question model is set to "Published" when the form is submitted and the Question instance is created. I'll need to adjust my form or view logic to set the correct status.

First, I adjusted the `form_valid` method in `views.py` to set the status to 1 (published) when the form is valid.

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.slug = form.cleaned_data['subject'].replace(' ', '-').lower()
    form.instance.status = 1  # Set the status to "Published". Assuming '1' corresponds to "Published" in your STATUS choices
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

This successfully creates a published instance that appears on the frontend in `questions.html`